# How long is a BAK exam valid for? (CASA Australia))

Tags: theory, australia, casa-regulations

I am looking to get back into flying, and I passed my BAK theory in 2016. Is that still valid? I want to go straight to PPL so I will be doing PPL theory anyway, just would save me a step, unless I don't need it? Thanks.